Custom wordpress theme in react and tailwind?
Searching the web and watching various tutorials I saw that it is possible to create custom plugins or custom blocks in React within the wordpress codebase.
My questions are:

Are we sure that by creating custom plugins and blocks in React these do not penalise SEO? (theoretically not as everything else on the page is rendered server side)
is it possible once I have created a custom plugin in react to import it into a page created in Elementor?
I would also like to add Tailwind to the bundle, where do you recommend installing it? Wordpress codebase or within the plugin itself... (I am a bit confused here, thank you for any clarification)

I'm asking if you have a tutorial that explains from top to bottom how to use react inside wordpress in the correct way, I've tried looking for some courses in Udemy but I don't know which one is the best.
Thanks a lot to whoever answers!!!
I have watched several tutorials but each time they implement React in a different way

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
